# Bootstrap Tags with inputmask possible?

Tags: tags, bootstrap-tags-input, jquery-inputmask

Im using
https://www.cssscript.com/tags-input-bootstrap-5/ for adding phone numbers.
Using with with regex works very well to validate input but theres some way to add input mask to it, so i can restrict user input before validation?

I expect to end up with the tags input, but with (may be a regex) inputmask so the user knows what to type in.